# how to debug/step through a simple java 'main' application using netbean?

Tags: java, netbeans

how to debug/step through a simple java 'main' application using netbean?

I want to set breakpoints and analyze the value of variables etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it hard to believe that there's nothing helpful in the NetBeans built-in help.

There's a debugging section in Sun's [NetBeans tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/tools/netbeans_part1/).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't find it hard to believe at all.

Comment: I'm not a NetBeans user, so I can't say how good their help is.  None of this is difficult with IntelliJ.